# Removing files containing, only, one row?

Tags: files, find, rm, wc, delete

I have large number of `csv` files saved within a folder. I would like to, only, delete the `csv` files that contains one row, how can I do that?

Comment: Use `wc -l` to select file then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

The number of lines in a file called `MyFile.csv` can be had with `wc -l <MyFile.csv`.  This number may be compared with `1` and the file removed using

```
if [ "$( wc -l <MyFile.csv )" -eq 1 ]; then
    rm -i MyFile.csv
fi
```

The `$(...)` is a command substitution that will be replaced by the output of the command within. The `-i` option to `rm` makes the utility ask for confirmation before deleting anything.

To generalize this to all CSV files in the current directory:

```
for filename in ./*.csv; do
    if [ "$( wc -l <"$filename" )" -eq 1 ]; then
        rm -i "$filename"
    fi
done
```

To generalize further to all CSV files in the current directory or anywhere below in any subdirectory:

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if [ "$( wc -l <"$pathname" )" -eq 1 ]; then
            rm -i "$pathname"
        fi
    done' {} +
```

---

Always back up your data, especially if you intend to test run scripted file deletions.